# Получение NULL при побитовой конъюнкции

Tags: c++, указатели

В проекте есть следующий код:

```cpp
#define SIZE 4096U

...

void *t_ptr = (void *) (*(uintptr_t *) test->field & ~(SIZE - 1U));
```

С помощью него необходимо получить указатель на первый элемент списка, так как память изначально была выделена с выравниваем `SIZE`.

*Адрес может быть, например, таким - `0x460028`.*

Однако результат выполнения этой строки равен `NULL`. Странность заключается в том, что при использовании другого указателя код вполне себе успешно функционирует.

`test` - это структура, описывающая некую область памяти. `field` - указатель на другую вспомогательную структуру.

```cpp
struct Test {
    ...

    struct Field *field;
};

struct Field {
    ...

    Test *test;
};

Test *test = (Test *) mem;
test->field = (Field *) mem1;
```

В данном случае, при `ptr` равном `0x4a0028`, будет возвращено `0x4a0000`.

*`ptr` - обычный указатель - `void *`*

```cpp
#define SIZE 4096U

...

void *t_ptr = (void *) (*(uintptr_t *) ptr & ~(SIZE - 1U));
```

Comment: Так а что такое `test->field`? Какой у него тип? И какой тип имеет `SIZE`? Почему эта информация не приведена в вопросе  сразу?

Comment: @AnT, обновил вопрос

Comment: Как проверяете на NULL? Какая ОС, архитектура процессора, компилятор?

Comment: Смотрю в отладчике. Windows 8 x64, MinGW x86_64 8.1.0-win32-seh

Comment: В некоторых реализациях NULL'ом считаются все указатели, значения которых меньше некоторого порогового адреса. В Windows на железном уровне это диапазон до 0x0000ffff включительно. Компилятор может его расширять, особенно в режиме отладки. Но в этом случае malloc не выделит память ниже границы.

Comment: думаю, ты имел в виду `(uintptr_t) ptr & ~(SIZE - 1U)` вместо своего привидения к указателю с разыменованием... ну и для надёжности `SIZE` следовало бы тоже привести к `uintptr_t` до инвертации...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, получилось. Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, что именно было не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> void *t_ptr = (void *) (*(uintptr_t *) ptr & ~(SIZE - 1U));
> ```

Выражение `*(uintptr_t *) ptr` означает «привести указатель `ptr` к типу ″указатель на `uintptr_t`″, а затем разыменовать» т.е. его результатом будет содержимое того участка памяти, на который указывает `ptr`, интерпретированное как целое `uintptr_t`.

Для того, чтобы получить значение указателя привидённое к `uintptr_t` надо сделать просто `(uintptr_t) ptr`.

Также если `sizeof(uintptr_t) > sizeof(unsigned)`, то выражение `~(SIZE - 1U)` перед выполнением побитового И будет расширено до `uintptr_t` по правилам беззнакового расширения т.е. даст число вида `0x_0000_0000_ffff_e000` вместо полностью заполненной битовой маски старших разрядов. Чтобы этого избежать надо привести выражение к `uintptr_t` до побитового НЕТ.

В итоге получение адреса страницы на которую указывает указатель должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
void *t_ptr = (void *) ((uintptr_t) ptr & ~((uintptr_t)SIZE - 1U));
```